# React.js Material-UI: Programmatically hide parent component tab from child component

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, redux, react-hooks

I am trying to hide a parent component tab from child component.

Providing my code snippet and sandbox below

Can someone please help? Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-8je9d

I have included the code below.

Tab2Component

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Button, Modal } from "react-bootstrap";

function Tab2ComponentFunction(props) {
  const { children, value, index, ...other } = props;

  return <div />;
}

export default function Tab2Component(props) {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(2);
  const [Tab2Show, setTab2Show] = useState(false);

  const onTab2Hide = () => {
    alert("onTab2Hide");
    setTab2Show(false);
    setValue(0); //goto tab1
  };

  //const handleChange = (event, newValue) => {
  //  setValue(newValue);
  //};

  return (
    <div>
      <Button className="mr10" variant="light" onClick={() => {}}>
        hide tab 2
      </Button>
      Tab2Component content
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what you want to do.

You need to pass the setValue function (from SimpleTabs) to the Tab2Component.
Then you have to call onTab2Hide during the onClick event.

[Try this](https://codesandbox.io/embed/material-demo-forked-zm2ik?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Comment: Thank you afreeman, I am not sure how to do that.

Comment: Thank you afreeman, it navigates to tab1 yet would like to also hide tab2.

Comment: Upvote and verify answer if this was helpful

So I added a hideTab2 state value in the SimpleTabs component.
If true hides tab 2 in the render, false displays tab 2 normally.
Passed setHideTab2 to the tab2Component, and setting hideTab2 to true inside the onclick event